# jQuery animation doesn't run fluently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am learning how to schedule animations via JavaScript, especially with the help of jQuery. I tried to blink some `h1` tags, but the animation doesn't seem to run fluently. It stops for a while and then go on.
The core animation code:

```
function animSlideHeading() {
  $('.slide h1').animate({
    opacity: .6
  }, 500, 'swing', function() {
    $('.slide h1').animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 500, 'swing', animSlideHeading);
  });
}
```

See [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/sufeh/1/edit?js,output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several elements matching the selector `$('.slide h1')`, so the callback is called multiple times, once for each element that is animated, and `animSlideHeading` runs more and more times the longer it goes, messing it up.

To solve it, you can use promises that resolve when the animations have completed for all the elements in the collection collectively

```
function animSlideHeading() {
    $('.slide h1').animate({
        opacity: 0.6
    }, 500, 'swing').promise().done(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 500, 'swing').promise().done(animSlideHeading);
    });
}
animSlideHeading();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wj65g/1/)